# Can blow-up of a surface be a product of two curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Is there any smooth projective surface $S$ over $k=\bar{k}$, such that the blow up $\tilde{S}$ along some point $x\in S$ can be written as $\tilde{S}=C_1\times C_2$ for two curves $C_i$?

Comment: Yes, if you had allowed $S$ to be singular.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thank you for your comment, can you name an exmple?

Comment: Let $C$ be a non-hyperelliptic curve. Consider $X= C \times C$ and the morphism $X\to Jac(C)$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$, where $Jac(C)$ is the Jacobian of $C$. (This is the "difference" map.)  This map is birational onto its image  $S$ and contracts the diagonal $\Delta \cong C$.  Note that $S$ is a normal projective (non-smooth) surface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. If not, let $E$ be the exceptional curve in $C_1\times C_2$. Then I claim that the projections $E$ to both $C_i$ are onto. If one of them is not, say to the second factor, then $E=C_1\times p$ for $p\in C_2$. But, then, $E^2=0\neq -1$, proving the claim. So, both $C_i$ are projective lines and the the Picard group of the product is as described in the deleted answer and easy to see that it has no curves of negative self-intersection.

Comment: Why must the $C_i$ be projective lines if the projections are onto? It seems like we would need the projections to be injective as well.

Comment: @heron1000 If a rational curve maps onto another curve, the image is a rational curve.

Comment: I see. But then to conclude from $C_i$ is rational that $C_i\cong \mathbb{P}^1$, we need $C_i$ to be smooth?

Comment: @heron1000 The blow up of a smooth surface at a point is smooth, so both $C_i$s must be smooth.